# How to perform actionDone event of EditText with Espresso

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-espresso

Question in the title.

I tried something like:

```
    onView(withId(R.id.search_edit_text))
            .perform(typeText("some"), pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
```

But it doesn't work. Keyboard is still shown and `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` not called. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question subject and tags. You type text in an EditText, not TextView.

Comment: It would help if you were to provide a little more info. It's very hard to see the problem if it isn't in this specific line. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
onView(withId(R.id.search_edit_text))
        .perform(typeText("some"), pressImeActionButton());
```

Answer (score 0):

I used KEYCODE_BACK and it works well. KEYCODE_ENTER not working on my device SAMSUNG A70

```
onView(withId(R.id.edit_text).perform(ViewActions.pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
```